# Include ServiceDependancy if checkbox selected WIX

Tags: wix, conditional-statements, wix3

Is it possible to include a ServiceDependency based on whether a checkbox was selected in a WIX application?

Answer (score 1):

Your check box control will likely set a property. You could then use a condition on a component to control if that component, which adds the service dependency, is installed.